# Estimating the extension of a surface

Tags: estimation, sampling, covariance

**Problem definition**

Consider the following sphere surface belonging into the 3D space $\mathbb{R}^3$
\begin{equation*}
\left(\frac{\xi}{R}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\eta}{R}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\zeta}{R}\right)^2=1
\end{equation*}
where the radius $R$ is an unknown parameter. Suppose to be able to observe $N$ points $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^N$ uniformly distributed (and independent) over the sphere surface. I'm currently trying to estimate the radius $R$ according to the obeservations.

**My desired approach**

The very simple idea is to compute the sample covariance
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\Sigma &\triangleq \frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^N (y_i-\bar{y})(y_i-\bar{y})'\\
\bar{y} &\triangleq \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N y_i
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
and then diagonalize it
\begin{equation*}D,\Lambda: \Sigma=D\,\Lambda\, D'\end{equation*}
Here the 3 eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^3$ in the Kernel
\begin{equation*}\Lambda = \text{diag}\left(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\right)\end{equation*}
approximate the square of the radius $R$, so my estimating strategy is given by the following formula
\begin{equation*}\hat{R}\triangleq \sqrt{\frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3}{3}}\end{equation*}

**Note**

I would like to find a solution that is based on the sample covariance because, actually, I'm trying to estimate the parameters of a superquadric surface with unknown position, orientation (roll-pitch-yaw angles), axis lengths (3 coordinate radii) and squareness. In this more complex scenario the sample covariance works like a charm for the orientation (roll, pitch and yaw can be immediately extracted from the diagonalizing matrix $D$) and also the eigen values $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^N$ they should be estimates of the 3 axis lengths.

**Observation**

Go back to the simplified problem with the sphere, where orientation and squareness are discharged.
It turns out that the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^N$ are biased estimates of the radius $R$.
I believe that this is natural because the observation are not scattered in space like a Gaussian or a uniform distribution, but rather they are precisely placed on the sphere surface. In the current problem there are no observation inside the sphere, and so the sample covariance is bigger than the same problem where the observations are also inside the sphere surface, e.g. uniformly.

**Question**

I have the suspect that is possible to compensate the bias in the estimate by introducing a suitable scale factor $\gamma$ in the sample covariance, with the objective to compensate the error due to the missing observations inside the  sphere.
\begin{equation*}\Sigma \mapsto \gamma\Sigma\end{equation*}
Hence the questions are the following:

1. is it correct my intuition regarding the scaling factor?
2. if it make sense to search for the scaling factor, how one can find it?
3. is there a better approach to solve my problem?

**EDIT**

Take in mind that I want to use the scaled sample covariance because of the extension to the superquadric case. Here for the sphere problem one can quite naively estimate the radius by just computing the distance of the observations from the object center (which can be estimated with mean observation).
This simple (and unbiased) solution cannot be extended to the superquadric case.

Comment: To confirm, you want to obtain an unbiased estimate of the radius of the sphere, correct?

Comment: yes mhdadk, that's correct

Comment: One unbiased estimator is the norm of the first point, because you assume you have sampled points that are "uniformly distributed (and independent) over the sphere surface," which *guarantees* the norm of each point is exactly $R.$  I suppose you intended to mean that the sample points are *not* distributed over the sphere, but can lie both outside and inside it according to some distribution.  To make any progress with that you need to tell us more about that distribution.

Comment: You are absolutely right whuber, indeed you can read my edit where I make clear your point. The difficulty is about the extension to the superquadric case, because in that case you cannot simply watch how much far the observations are with respect the center (you have 3 different radii, like the ellipsoidal case). I'm discussing the sphere case because is simpler and can be used as a starting point to then face out the superquadric case. In this case (sphere) and the complex one (superquadric) the point are generated uniformly over the surface. There is no a specific distribution.

Comment: To make the problem more clear: In my simulations I generate a big number of observation with the uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}([-R, R]^3)$, then I discharge all the observations that does not satisfy the cartesian equation of the sphere. As a result of this process, I end up with a random number of observation that uniformly distributed over the surface of the sphere. I hope to have clarified my problem.

Comment: I'm sorry; I cannot make any sense of the distinctions you are trying to make.  Because you still insist you have data "uniformly distributed over the surface," my first remark still applies. It might help to ask the question you actually have, rather than posing some simplification that might have lost the essence of the problem.

Comment: Ok whuber, thanks for the feedback. I'll write as soon as possible a new post where I define the original problem. Maybe this simplified version makes my point more confused rather than more clear.